# Find element with fewest children?

Tags: jquery

How would I use jQuery to find an element (`tr`) with the fewest amount of children (`td`'s) in my table?

Comment: AFAIK there must be  same  numbers of `td` in each `tr` in a `table` either there may b `colspan` or `rowspan` attribute. are u intrested to know which tr's td have maximum `colspan`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tr = $('tr');
    tr.sort(function(a, b) { 
        return $(a).children('td').length - $(b).children('td').length;
    });
    // $(tr).first() is your TR with fewest TDs
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/ebgVa/)

Comment: Works nicely. Added a fiddle example.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably encapsulate that into a custom jQuery wrapper method.

```
(function($) {

    // blah with function name
    $.fn.fewestChildren = function () {

        var $this = $(this).filter('tr'), 
            bookmark = $this.eq(0)
            ;

        $this.not(bookmark).each(function () {
            var $t = $(this);
            if (bookmark.children('td').length > $t.children('td').length) {
                bookmark = $t;
            }
        });

        return bookmark;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

So that I can just use that like:

```
var foo = $('#mytable tr').fewestChildren();
```

I'd really love to see a solution without having to make use of a `bookmark` variable though.